# Android auto start activity (app starts twice)

Tags: android, android-activity, autostart

I would like to run my application when the boot up of my device has finished.
For this I have found some helpful code in the internet:

```
public class MyBootCompleteReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
    {
        if(intent.getAction() != null && intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)) 
        {  
           Intent pushIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);  
           pushIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

           context.startActivity(pushIntent);  
        } 
    }
}
```

And the Manifest entry:

```
    <receiver android:name="MyBootCompleteReceiver" android:enabled="true" android:exported="false" android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />          
        </intent-filter>      
    </receiver>
```

Now if I boot up my device the application seems to start up twice.
Then I tried to replace the "NEW_TASK" Flag with the "REORDER_TO_FRONT" (I have also read this in the internet) but if i do so, my application crashes on boot up.
Also if I remove all flags, it crashes too.

Hope you can help!

Comment: why does it crash? any error logs?

Comment: No, unfortunately not (because my eclipse doesn´t log after booting).

After unlocking the screen the typical black dialog with (application has unexpectly crashed -> force close) shows up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So...

after long long testing I found out that the problem should be my physical tablet (asus eee pad transfortem android version 3.2.1).

Because I have tried it in the emulator (android version 3.2) and there the source code I posted (on the top of this thread) worked quite well.
No start up twice of the app and no errors. 
Even if you remove the "pushIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);" code it works.

So it seems that I have to wait for an update (maybe on android 4.0).

I hope this helps somebody, who has the same problem.

Comment: If you use high priority for your `BroadcastReceiver`, then remove it. I did it, and it seemed the system did not yet... boot completely, and my app started, then crashed. I'm not sure if it was called twice. But after removing high priority, the app worked fine.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't see your xml. But I got problem looked same to yours, and what I did to solve it is above comment.

Comment: How can I remove high priority? And where?

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't see your xml in the first comment. So that comments is useless. For example about priority: `<intent-filter android:priority="2147483647" >`. You can try this code to test, it makes you feel safe that your app is executed only once at boot time: `new android.os.Handler().postDelayed(new Thread() { /*start your app here*/ }, 10000}`. Also Eclipse can log everything after the emulator started. You just open `LogCat` to see logs.

Answer (score 0):

Use the boot complete intent filter in you activity in you manifest file.

```
<activity ....>
     <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />          
    </intent-filter>      
</activity>
```

I hope it helps...